# Error from Model - call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting this error:

`call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'getRole' (View: C:\wamp\www\lc2\laravel\app\views\account\profile.blade.php)`

In the model `User.php`, I have a function like this.

```
public function getRole(){

       $roleid=Auth::user()->role;
       switch($roleid){
           case 1:
               $role='Administrator';
               break;
           case 2:
               $role='Manager';
               break;
           case 3:
               $role='Professor';
               break;
           case 4:
               $role='Student';
               break;
           default:
               $role='';
       }
       return $role;
}
```

In another page `profile.blade.php`, I'm getting the user role like this: 
`{{Auth::user()->getRole()}}`

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already call `getRole()` on the current user why are you using `Auth::user()->role` inside `getRole()`?

This should work just fine:

```
public function getRole(){

   switch($this->role){
       case 1:
           $role='Administrator';
           break;
       case 2:
           $role='Manager';
           break;
       case 3:
           $role='Professor';
           break;
       case 4:
           $role='Student';
           break;
       default:
           $role='';
   }
   return $role;
}
```

Comment: Getting an error: 'Using $this when not in object context'

Comment: Hmm... Is `Auth::user()` really returning an instance of the user model?

Comment: Actually when I used `{{User::getRole()}}` with my function definition, it worked.

Comment: Ahh I thought you where using `Auth::user()->getRole()`. Can you try this with my function code?

Comment: Are you sure you got `public function getRole(){` and not `public static function getRole(){`?

Comment: My bad! it was public static!